# SSDT to open existing reports on existing report server

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I don't know how to open existing reports on existing report server using SSDT.
I update my computer to SQL Server 2014 and SSDT.
Previously when I used SQL Server 2008, I used Report Builder to open existing reports by connecting existing Report Server.
How could I do like that using SSDT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSDT-BI is the SQL Server 2014 equivalent of the Business Intelligence Developer Studio (BIDS) development environment shipped with earlier versions of SQL Server. It is not a replacement for Report Builder, which is a seperate development tool. For SQL Server 2014 you will need to download the latest version of Report Builder from the Microsoft website:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=42301